# Drupal sidebar Navigation links

Tags: php, drupal, menu, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am styling a Drupal 7 website.

I want to create sidebar menu as shown in image on drupal platform version 7.

The menu has to be dynamic, so that if I add a new menu item I can do it easily and also able to add small image icon.

[image: Template image]

Comment: What version of Drupal? If it's 7, it's under Structure > Menu, and then add your links to a secondary navigation. Then under Structure > Blocks, add your menu to the correct zone.

Comment: @Layke adding menu to block is not my problem, what i want is to add small images which are in round circles as shown in left sidebar with menus

Comment: You should have said that in your original post. Please update your question.

Comment: @Layke 4th line does make sense ? please read question before you vote for it

Comment: You've got a few ways of doing it. You could use CSS since each menu item gets a unique ID, but you could also install a module, such as views, and use that. By far the simplest solution would be to just use CSS to set an image for the menu list item based on the ID of the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module [menu_attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) allows you to set the `ID` or `CLASS` attributes for each menu item. Hope this is what you needed :)